# resteasy integration with dsl-json - unable to register reader

Tags: java, json, rest, resteasy, dsl

I'm trying to integrate dsl-json with resteasy for de/serialization.But it throws an exception

```
 java.io.IOException: Unable to find reader for provided type: class com.x.y.api.v1.resource.A and fallback serialization is not registered.
17:04:51,705 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Found reader for: class com.x.y.api.v1.resource.A so try deserializing into that instead?
17:04:51,705 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Alternatively, try initializing system with custom fallback or register specified type using registerReader into class com.dslplatform.json.DslJson
17:04:51,705 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.dslplatform.json.DslJson.showErrorMessage(DslJson.java:650)
17:04:51,706 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.dslplatform.json.DslJson.deserialize(DslJson.java:980)
17:04:51,706 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at com.x.y.provider.DSLJsonProvider.readFrom(DSLJsonProvider.java:41)
17:04:51,706 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:61)
17:04:51,706 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:60)
17:04:51,706 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53)
17:04:51,707 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:34)
17:04:51,707 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:55)
17:04:51,707 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59)
17:04:51,707 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:55)
17:04:51,707 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:151)
17:04:51,708 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:91)
17:04:51,708 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:114)
17:04:51,708 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
17:04:51,708 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
17:04:51,708 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
17:04:51,709 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
17:04:51,709 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
17:04:51,709 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
17:04:51,710 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
17:04:51,710 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
```

My DSLJsonProvider class looks like this.

```
    package com.x.y.provider;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
    import java.lang.reflect.Type;

    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

    import com.dslplatform.json.DslJson;
    import com.dslplatform.json.JsonReader;
    import com.dslplatform.json.JsonReader.ReadObject;
    import com.dslplatform.json.JsonWriter;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Provider
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})
    public class DSLJsonProvider extends DslJson implements MessageBodyWriter, MessageBodyReader {

        @Override
        public boolean isReadable(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType mediaType) {
            return true;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public Object readFrom(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType mediaType,
                MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            DslJson<Object> dslJson = new DslJson<Object>();
            try {
                dslJson.registerReader(type,null);//Here I need help
                return dslJson.deserialize(type, entityStream, new byte[1024]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                entityStream.close();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isWriteable(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType mediaType) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public long getSize(Object t, Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType mediaType) {
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public void writeTo(Object t, Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
                        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter();
            try {
//Need help to register writer
                writer.toStream(entityStream);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Edit 1:
My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.x.y</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>project-web</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.20.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.20.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dslplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>dsl-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dslplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>dsl-json-java8</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>com.dslplatform.json.CompiledJsonProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm kinda blocked at trying to register readers and writers.Any lead is appreciated.

Resource :
dsl-json : https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it's unable to find reader for: `com.x.y.api.v1.resource.A`

It's either you forgot to add `@CompiledJson` to that class or for some reason it was not picked up with `ServiceLoader`.

If you want to register your own reader for `JsonReader.ReadObject` you can look into [geom readers](https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/dslplatform/json/JavaGeomConverter.java) although I think you probably just want to add annotation for compiler to pick it up.

Processor for those annotations lives in a separate library (processor) so mostly probably you didn't include it or added it as annotation processor.

You need to get rid of dslJson.registerReader(type,null); since that will override correct reader.

I updated dsl-json README, since I did encounter such errors occasionally. Namely: "During startup DslJson loads services through ServiceLoader. For this to work META-INF/services/com.dslplatform.json.Configuration must exist with the content of dsl_json.json.ExternalSerialization which is the class crated during compilation step. In certain scenarios this file is not copied to APK or to the appropriate jar/war file. You can work around it by creating such file in your project under src/main/resources/META-INF/services as workaround for the used package/build tool."

I would be interested more in your setup so if this fixes the problem for you please submit an issue on the repository so it can be properly resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!I've @CompiledJson in place for the class.And I have edited the question to include my pom.xml.Is that right way of including the annotation processor?

Comment: You are still missing dependency to the processor (dsl-json-processor).

Comment: I've added that dependency.But still no luck.It still says unable to find the reader.When I checked in the debugging mode, reader is passed as null.Do you have any Idea whats going on with this? Thanks!

Comment: correct reader is picked up during DslJson initialization. You can inspect reader map to see if there is something there. If everything is correctly setup, all your @CompiledJson types should be there

Comment: I checked the readers Map..And I found that None of my @CompiledJson types are present.I see only default types in "jsonReaders" Map and "{ }" in "jsonObjectReaders" Map.And also, I see  fallback and context also null.I'm not able to corner what I'm missing :(

Comment: ;( That should be only possible if services were not correctly loaded. Please check target folder for dsl_json.json.ExternalSerialization and META-INF/services/com.dslplatform.CompiledJson with that registration. Not sure why would be missing. Try registering it manually and let me know: https://github.com/zapov/LoganSquare/blob/master/BenchmarkDemo/app/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.dslplatform.json.Configuration

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue, and fixed by add default constructor to deserialized class